# ¿Cómo verificar si existe un objeto con una determinada propiedad (LocalDate) leyendo intervalos de objetos LocalDate?

Tags: java, java-stream

Yo estoy usando este método para recorrer día por día entre dos fechas dadas:

```
private static void fillFeriaeAdventus() {
    LocalDate start = getPrimaAdventu();
    LocalDate end = getNativitate();
    List<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
            .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    dates.forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e);
    });
}
```

Esto funciona bien y yo puedo ver las fechas que se generan, por ejemplo:

```
2021-11-28
2021-11-29
2021-11-30
2021-12-01
2021-12-02
2021-12-03
2021-12-04
2021-12-05
2021-12-06
2021-12-07
2021-12-08
2021-12-09
2021-12-10
2021-12-11
2021-12-12
2021-12-13
2021-12-14
2021-12-15
2021-12-16
2021-12-17
2021-12-18
2021-12-19
2021-12-20
2021-12-21
2021-12-22
2021-12-23
2021-12-24
```

Ahora bien, yo tengo un `ArrayList` como este:

```
private static ArrayList<Celebration> mCalendar = new ArrayList<>();
```

Donde voy guardando objetos de la clase `Celebration` que tienen una propiedad de tipo `LocalDate` con su *getter*:

```
public class Celebration {
    private int id, mTime, mColor;
    private String mName;
    private LocalDate mDate;

    public Celebration(int id, LocalDate theDate, String mName, int mTime, int mColor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mDate=theDate;
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mTime = mTime;
        this.mColor=mColor;
    }


    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Yo quiero seguir llenando el objeto `mCalendar` dentro de `fillFeriaeAdventus()`, **pero sólo me interesa meter en `mCalendar` aquellos que no existan previamente**.

¿De qué forma podría lograrlo?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma eficiente de hacerlo, que toma tiempo lineal sería la siguiente:

Nombremos `m` como la longitud de los elementos en `mCalendar` y `n` como la longitud de los elementos en `dates` (adentro de `fillFeriaeAdventus`).

1. Hacer una copia de `mCalendar`, pero guardar los valores en un HashMap para permitir búsqueda `O(1)`, antes de empezar a agregar elementos a `mCalendar`. Esto toma tiempo `O(m)`
2. De la lista `dates` agregar a `mCalendar` los elementos que **no** se encuentren en el HashMap. Gracias a que es un HashMap, esto toma tiempo `O(n)`.

De esta forma aseguramos que a `mCalendar` ingresen objetos que no sean duplicados, o que no existieran ya previamente en el arreglo.

La implementación sería la siguiente:

```
class Main {
    public static ArrayList<LocalDate> mCalendar = new ArrayList<>();

    private static void fillFeriaeAdventus() {
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 28);
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 24);
        List<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // copiamos las fechas ya existentes en mCalendar en un hashmap para permitir busqueda O(1)
        HashMap<LocalDate, Boolean> datesMap = new HashMap<>();
        mCalendar.forEach(date -> {datesMap.put(date, true);}); // O(m)
        // del hashmap realmente solo nos importa la llave, el valor no lo usamos

        // agregamos más fechas
        // vamos a agregar las que están en dates
        // pero que no estén ya previamente en mCalendar
        mCalendar.addAll(
                dates.stream()
                        .filter(Predicate.not(datesMap::containsKey)) // la busqueda se hace en O(1)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ); // O(n)

        // La otra opción es hacerlo con un for
        /*for (LocalDate date : dates)
            if (!datesMap.containsKey(date))
                mCalendar.add(date);*/

        System.out.println("mCalendar.size(): " + mCalendar.size());
        mCalendar.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Primera invocación: Debería agregar elementos al arreglo");
        fillFeriaeAdventus();

        System.out.println("Segunda invocación: NO debería agregar elementos al arreglo pues serían duplicados");
        fillFeriaeAdventus();
    }
}
```

Si lo ejecutas verás que en efecto, la segunda invocación no agregó elementos duplicados.

Ahora, la desventaja de esto es que se debe ocupar más memoria, prácticamente el doble de memoria que se ocupa realmente para `mCalendar`.

Se podría modificar el algoritmo para que no ocupara tanta memoria pero entonces tomaría tiempo `O(m log(m))` pues se requeriría el arreglo ordenado para realizar búsqueda binaria.

**Nota final sobre el hashcode de la clase `LocalDate`**:

El [código](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java) de openjdk es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int yearValue = year;
    int monthValue = month;
    int dayValue = day;
    return (yearValue & 0xFFFFF800) ^ ((yearValue << 11) + (monthValue << 6) + (dayValue));
}
```

En ese caso sería seguro utilizar el algoritmo pues se tomarían dos objetos `LocalDate` iguales si sus fechas son iguales.

No sé cómo sea el hashcode en otras implementaciones pero supongo que se mantiene esa condición de que dos objetos `LocalDate` son iguales si sus fechas son iguales.

Espero que esto te sirva, saludos.

### Edit 1

Aquí está el cambio en la solución inicial tomando en cuenta que se deben guardar en `mCalendar` objetos de tipo `Celebration`.

```
class Main {
    public static ArrayList<Celebration> mCalendar = new ArrayList<>();

    private static void fillFeriaeAdventus() {
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 28);
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 24);
        List<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // copiamos las fechas ya existentes en mCalendar en un hashmap para permitir busqueda O(1)
        HashMap<LocalDate, Boolean> datesMap = new HashMap<>();
        mCalendar.forEach(date -> {datesMap.put(date.getDate(), true);}); // O(n)

        // agregamos más fechas
        // vamos a agregar las que están en dates
        // pero que no estén ya previamente en mCalendar
        /*AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);
        mCalendar.addAll(
                dates.stream()
                        .filter(Predicate.not(datesMap::containsKey)) // la busqueda se hace en O(1)
                        .map(date -> new Celebration(n.getAndIncrement(), date)) // convertimos o mapeamos los objetos LocalDate a Celebration
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ); // O(n)*/

        // La otra opción es hacerlo con un for
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); ++i)
            if (!datesMap.containsKey(dates.get(i)))
                mCalendar.add(new Celebration(i, dates.get(i)));

        System.out.println("mCalendar.size(): " + mCalendar.size());
        mCalendar.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Primera invocación: Debería agregar elementos al arreglo");
        fillFeriaeAdventus();

        System.out.println("Segunda invocación: NO debería agregar elementos al arreglo pues serían duplicados");
        fillFeriaeAdventus();
    }

    private static class Celebration {
        private int idx;
        private LocalDate localDate;

        public Celebration(int idx, LocalDate localDate) {
            this.idx = idx;
            this.localDate = localDate;
        }

        public LocalDate getDate() {
            return this.localDate;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.localDate.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso no hay mucho cambio salvo por el `.map()` para crear los objetos `Celebration`. Sin embargo, dado que uno de los fundamentos de la programación funcional es que no debe haber modificaciones de estado (como con el iterador `n`), decidí comentar esa solución para preferir la normal con un `for`. Además, quizá tenga mejor performance (pero no estoy seguro).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Benjamín. `mCalendar` es un `ArrayList` de objetos `Celebration`, y para incluir en él los nuevos objetos yo necesito usar el constructor (la fecha es sólo una de las propiedades del objeto). ¿De qué forma se resolvería esa parte en el código que propones? Yo encontré una solución basada en `filter` y `anyMatch` que me funciona (ver auto-respuesta). Agradezco tus apreciaciones al respecto.

Comment: No hay de qué @A.Cedano , ya agregué las modificaciones correspondientes y perdona la tardanza. Igual ya vi tu solución y se ve bien, es quizá más legible que la mía lo cual es también importante. Sin embargo, veo que tiene complejidad `O(nm)`, lo cual puede ser malo si alguno de los dos es muy grande, de lo contrario supongo que no hay mucho problema.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he logrado con `filter` y `anyMatch`, obteniendo solamente las fechas que no existan al usar `!` en el filtro:

```
            .filter(date -> !mCalendar.stream()
```

Este sería el método completo:

```
private static void fillFeriaeAdventus() {
    LocalDate start = getPrimaAdventu();
    LocalDate end = getNativitate();
    List<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
            .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
            .filter(date -> !mCalendar.stream()
                    .anyMatch(mCelebration ->
                            mCelebration.getDate().equals(date)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    /*
       Añadimos las fechas ya filtradas al array
    */
    AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);
    dates.forEach(e -> {
        mCalendar.add(new Celebration(
                n.getAndIncrement(),
                e,
                String.format("%s de %s", e.getDayOfMonth(), e.getMonth()),
                1, 4));
    });
}
```